# background-image with css

Tags: css

Why the background image not working with

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/gbvqmW)**

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: red;"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 385px;
  background-image: url(http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/082/a/c/png_grass_by_moonglowlilly-d5z1o5t.png);
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3f4858;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: pelase, could you explain what exactly is *not working*?

Comment: the inline property background:red overrides the background image...http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/gbvqmW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the already mentioned spelling error

---

The problem here is with the size of your container and the size of your background image. Your image has a lot of space on top and you will see nothing for the size of you container. Check if you change the `background-size` property to:

> background-size: 100% 100%;

#### [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByYMRm)

For the porperty [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) you can also use `contain`:

> the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area

#### [AnotherDemo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYrwyw)

Comment: I want to make it with repeat-x if i use this think then the background-repat is not working.

Comment: I was looking for this answer absolutely. However, there is one thing I do not understand why someone gave me the minus points.

Comment: @innovation I don't know each user here can give an "opinion" with votes. But on the future try to make your question more clear .... like why it isn't working? what is the expected output. But to me is pretty fine includes code and a demo and it's pretty obvious the problem Upvoted

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful response.

Comment: Can i ask you something ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:385px;
  background-image:url('http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/082/a/c/png_grass_by_moonglowlilly-d5z1o5t.png');
 background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
 background-size:cover;
 border-bottom:1px solid #3f4858;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:red;">
```

Answer (score 1):

The image is of size 1024x819px and the grass is starting from `232px` from top so you need to position your background image or change your div.container size so as to fit the image within the given size.

Demo-1 with container size changed:

[Demo-1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPyogY)

Demo-2 with image position changed with your code snippet only.:

[Demo-2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPyovY)

just notice background-position I have changed to 0px -232px;

Answer (score 0):

Your `width: 100%` depends on width of parent element. And its not set. Thats why. So change your CSS to this:

```
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:385px;
  background-image:url(http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/082/a/c/png_grass_by_moonglowlilly-d5z1o5t.png);
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size:cover;
  border-bottom:1px solid #3f4858;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}
```

Also why you have in your HTML `style="background-color:red;"`? Do you want to have as background image `png_grass_by_moonglowlilly-d5z1o5t.png` or red color? Or you want to have in transparency of that PNG image red color?

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwQVjK)

Comment: thanks for help . It will help. But i don't understand why someone give me minus vote :/